# What is the best practice for transaction management when using Hibernate and Spring together?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

As best practice, when using hibernate and spring together which transaction management should I use, Spring's transaction management or  Hibernate's transaction management?
I understand that both provides transaction management but since they are usually used together I dont know which to use.  Does it depend on the situation or type of transaction to be handled or is there a rule of thumb when using these frameworks together?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring is supposed to **help you** use Hibernate's transaction management - it's additional level of abstraction that simply works:) It is much more convenient marking which parts should be transactional (therefore handled by Spring).

**Edit:**
Oh I almost forgot. With Spring's transactional support you will write LESS code ;)